# Overlay not working in showcaseTemplate

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml, tvjs

I am simply modifying the showcaseTemplate that comes with the TVMLCatalog example by modifying the images `src` and adding an overlay to the lookup:

```
<carousel>  
     <section>  
          <lockup>  
               <img src="${this.BASEURL}resources/images/templates/gft.jpg" width="500" height="600" />  
               <overlay>  
                    <title>Hello, this is title</title>  
               </overlay>  
          </lockup>  
     </section>  
</carousel>
```

But the overlay is not showing

this is what the XCODE log shows:

```
2015-12-07 11:25:47.851 TVMLCatalog[3953:3684153] #T:[Main] #Notice #SYSTEM : Template element: <IKViewElement: 0x7fcee0781f20>   
2015-12-07 11:25:47.858 TVMLCatalog[3953:3684153] #T:[Main] #Notice #SYSTEM : Template controller: <_TVLoadingViewController: 0x7fcee04ba960>   
2015-12-07 11:25:47.864 TVMLCatalog[3953:3684153] #T:[Main] #Notice #SYSTEM : Template element: <IKViewElement: 0x7fcee2176a50>   
2015-12-07 11:25:47.865 TVMLCatalog[3953:3684153] #T:[Main] #Notice #SYSTEM : Template controller: <_TVShowcaseTemplateController: 0x7fcee0799c90>   
Dec  7 11:25:47  TVMLCatalog[3953] <Error>: ImageIO: CreateMetadataFromXMPBufferInternal  Threw error #203 (Duplicate property or field node)  
Dec  7 11:25:47  TVMLCatalog[3953] <Error>: ImageIO: CreateMetadataFromXMPBufferInternal  Threw error #203 (Duplicate property or field node)  
2015-12-07 11:25:48.996 TVMLCatalog[3953:3684153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.  
  Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.   
  Try this:   
  (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;   
  (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.   
  (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)   
(  
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fcee0564910 h=--& v=--& V:[_TVStackingPosterView:0x7fcee051a1e0(46)]>",  
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcee0554000 V:[TVLabel:0x7fcee0561020'Image1'(62)]>",  
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcee0564250 V:|-(0)-[TVLabel:0x7fcee0561020'Image1']   (Names: '|':_TVStackingPosterView:0x7fcee051a1e0 )>",  
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcee0564720 TVLabel:0x7fcee0561020'Image1'.bottom == _TVStackingPosterView:0x7fcee051a1e0.bottom>"  
)  
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint   
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcee0564720 TVLabel:0x7fcee0561020'Image1'.bottom == _TVStackingPosterView:0x7fcee051a1e0.bottom>  
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.  
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Note that I have never worked with Swift or Objective-C before. So I am totally lost here.
Any help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found out it is a known issue:

More Information in Apple developer forums:

- [Overlay not working in showcaseTemplate](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/93137)
- [Device Log Spam](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/70895)
- [Getting autolayout errors with showcaseTemplate in TVML](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/89526)
- [Current document DOM manipulation issue in beta 2](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/66274)

Several bug reports have been filed to Apple.